# Hardcode strings into a DateTimeFormatter format

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to hardcode specific strings into a datetime format.

```
val cst= ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")
val zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now
val ts = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(cst)
//1900-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z
println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS").format(ts))
```

I am attempting to print the `ts` value in this format `1900-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z`.  How would this be done? Simply adding `T` and `Z` at the end causes failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single-quote marks, `'`, to specify added characters.

```
println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'").format(ts))
```